# How many dominos in a pack?

Tags: combinatorics

I was playing dominos the other day and when I was done I wanted to know how many dominos I should I have if I didn't loose one. So I started by drawing a chart in my head. We have $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$ on the top and on the side. That makes $7(7)$, but we double counted all except$(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),...(6,6)$ as we have counted $(6,1)=(1,6)$ as two separate dominos when only one domino with a $6$ and $1$ exists.  (each piece is a unique set of two elements I think). So we have:

$$\frac{7(7)-7}{2}+7=28$$

Dominos. But why can't we do:

$${7 \choose 2}=21??$$

Because we have $7$ numbers and we want to choose $2$ of them where order does not matter.

Also as a plus, can someone tell me why:

$${8 \choose 2}=1+2+3+4+5+6+7=28$$

Gives the right answer, or is this just a coincidence?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: It's a triangle:
\begin{align}
(6,6)
\\
(5,5)(5,6)
\\
(4,4)(4,5){4,6)
\\
(3,3)(3,4)(3,5){3,6)
\\
(2,2)(2,3)(2,4)(2,5){2,6)
\\
(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(1,4)(1,5){1,6)
\\
(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)(0,3)(0,4)(0,5){0,6)
\end{align}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A domino tile is a rectangle with two square ends, each of which is imprinted with $0$ to $6$ spots.  A set of dominoes contains a unique piece for each possible combination of $0$ to $6$ spots.  There are $\binom{7}{2}$ ways to select a domino in which the ends have different numbers of spots and $\binom{7}{1}$ ways to select a domino in which the two ends have the same number of spots.  Hence, the number of dominoes in a set is 
$$\binom{7}{2} + \binom{7}{1}$$
As you observed, 
$$\binom{7}{2} + \binom{7}{1} = \binom{8}{2}$$ 
which is a consequence of Pascal's Identity
$$\binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k - 1} = \binom{n + 1}{k}$$

Answer (score 1):

The $\binom{7}{2}$ doesn't include the combinations $(0,0), (1,1)$, etc.

Comment: Thanks this also makes sense when I have $0,1,2,..6$ and choose $2$ I have I have to choose $2$ different numbers if I'm going to use n choose k.